# Facebook login: PHP SDK v5 reask email

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

When a client removes the email from the info provided in facebook php sdk v5 how can I force Facebook to show the same menu as this image shows

[image]

I have a popup on my website, and this popup says that the user needs to give the email and after the popup it will redirect to Facebook login, the same as the first :

```
       require_once"../facebook/Facebook-php-sdk-v5/autoload.php";

        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
          'app_id' => '****************',
          'app_secret' => '********************************',
          'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
        ]);

        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

        $permissions = ['email', 'user_likes']; // optional
        $loginUrl2 = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://example.com/facebook/fbcallback.php', $permissions);
```

I'v been looking all over the internet and I could not find anything that reprompts the same login panel after the client already logged in but rejected the email how can I do this?

Comment: Search for rerequest on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking . But be aware that you are not allowed to pop the dialog again automatically if the user removes that permission. You have to explain to the user why you need the permission and have a button that the user clicks if they change their mind and want to give your app the permission

Comment: and how do I pass the:  auth_type=rerequest along with my request in the php sdk.

Comment: FacebookRedirectLoginHelper has a dedicated method for that.